# Pivoting Data into a time series format

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, pivot-table, transform

I'm having trouble getting my data into the format I want in a quicker way than copy and pasting. Right now my data looks something like this:

[image: current]

I would like to pivot it so that I have category in a column next to date so it will look something like this:

[image: wanted]

I feel that this should be a simple transformation but I can't figure it out.

Any help on this would be appreciated!

Comment: Power Query will be a better choose.

Answer (score 0):

If you have just two categories:

Date column formula:

```
=INDIRECT("$A"&(ROUND(ROW()/2,0)-MOD(ROW(),2)+1))
```

Value column formula:

```
=INDIRECT(ADDRESS((ROUND(ROW()/2,0)-MOD(ROW(),2)+1),MOD(ROW(),2)+2))
```

The date column formula will pull from column A row 1 for two rows, then move to row 2, etc...

The Value column will follow the same row format as date column and bounce back and fourth between columns 2 and 3 (B and C).

You should be able to copy and paste one row with these two formulas down your sheet.